# Solve $(z-1)^3=9(\overline{z}-1)$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I would like to solve the complex equation $(z-1)^3=9(\overline{z}-1)$.

Here's what I did:

- Attempt 1: $w=z-1$, $w^3=9[cos(-\alpha)+isin(-\alpha)]-9$
- Attempt 2: $(x+iy-1)^3=9(x-iy-1)$
- Attempt 3: $z^3-3z^2+3z-1=9(\overline{z}-1)$

But it seems like neither of those attempts takes me to the solutions.

Comment: Let $y = (z-1)/3$. Then $y^3 = \bar y$. This means if $|y| \neq 0$, then $|y| = 1$ so $\bar y = 1/y$.

Answer (score 1):

With $y=z-1$ you have $$y^3=9\bar y$$

Thus $$|y^3|=9|y|$$
We get $|y|=0$ or 
$|y|=3$

Thus $y=0$ or $y=3e^{i\theta }$

Plugging in $$y^3=9\bar y$$ gives us $e^{4i\theta}=1$

You can continue from there.